# Are there 13¼" snare skins?

Tags: snare-drum

I’m part of an amateur drumming band where we don’t have a lot of knowledge about music and instruments and we prefer to use old and sometimes slightly broken instruments rather than spending money on buying new stuff. Most of our instruments have been donated to us at some point when no one of us has been part of the band yet, so we don’t know a lot about them or where they come from.

Recently one of our Snare skins broke and we have tried to replace it. The Snare is a bit unusual, the screws have a square head, but one that is bigger than usual, so our regular tools don’t fit on it. Also, the circumference of the drum is about 33.5 cm, which is a bit less than 13¼". We tried to fit several different brands of 13" Snare skin, but non of them fit at all, even when using a lot of force. The skin that was previously on the drum looks like it was a regular 13" skin where someone broke the metal ring in order to make it fit. So it is no wonder that the skin broke at some point.

My question is, is 13¼" Snares something that exists? Or do 13" snare skins vary so much in size that some brands might fit on this drum? Are 13¼" skins sold anywhere? (We are based in Germany.)

Comment: What is the nametag on the drum?

Answer (score 3):

Remo makes their [Classic Fit](https://remo.com/products/product/ambassador-coated-classic-fit/) line which are made for "oversized drums made prior to the mid 60’s." They appear to be available in a 13" size.

I'd assume other manufacturers have similar lines to this.

> If the dimension is a whole number such as 12”or less, then our standard 12” batter head will work fine. If the dimension is a larger than 12”, such as 12-1/8”, then our Classic Fit batter head should work.
>   https://support.remo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017900091

Comment: I found the exact size specifications [here](https://support.remo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029336752-Classic-Fit-Sizing-Specs), so the 13" Classic Fit fits a diameter of 13.125" / 33.3 cm. So this might fit. I will report back once I ordered it.